# How to dynamic insert data from templatetag

Tags: django, django-templates

I have many different models and each does something different.
In template i want use templatetag ex: {% loadmodules 'left' %} which loads the appropriate modules

For example i have module "menu" (model menu and model menuitem with relation to menu) and if module menu have position 'left', it being loaded in template but in such a way as to display a specific HTML with retrieved data.

How to convert templatetag on the list of results returned from the function of a module?

Comment: I can't understand what do you exactly need, but there are two possible solutions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/ - create your own templatetag or use includes.

Comment: Thanks! @register.inclusion_tag is my friend.

Comment: I'm glad that you found solution, so I'll repost comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand what do you exactly need, but there are two possible solutions: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags) - create your own templatetag or use includes.